# How to reset placeholder in Chakra Select using react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, chakra-ui

I mapped the countries in select. When I reset the select the placeholder is still the country name, but the value is reset to undefined.

```
const countries = [
  { label: 'France', value: 'FR' },
  { label: 'Germany', value: 'DE' },
];
```

```
const defaultValues = {
  country: undefined,
};
```

```
const Select: FC<Props> = ({
  options,
  onSelect,
  placeholder = 'Select option',
  ...props
}) => {
  const handleSelect = useCallback(
    (ev) => {
      const { value } = ev.target;
      const select = value ? options.find((opt) => opt.value === value) : null;
      onSelect(select);
    },
    [options]
  );

  return (
    <ChakraSelect
      onChange={handleSelect}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      {...props}
    >
      {options?.map((opt) => (
        <option key={opt.label} value={opt.value}>
          {opt.label}
        </option>
      ))}
    </ChakraSelect>
  );
};

export default Select;
```

```
<FormControl isInvalid={errors.country}>
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name='country'
    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => {
      return (
        <Select
          onSelect={onChange}
          options={countries}
          placeholder='Select country'
          value={value?.value}
        />
      );
    }}
    rules={{
      required: {
        value: true,
        message: 'Country is required',
      },
    }}
  />
```

Reset using react-hook-form:

```
reset({...defaultValues});
```

Here is the result after reset, value: undefined, but the placeholder is still the country name:
[image]